# Proof of identity $(\mathrm{e}^z)^w$ for complex numbers $z,w$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

Let $z,w$ complex numbers. Than one get:
$$\begin{align*}
(\mathrm{e}^z)^w&= (\exp(z\cdot \log(e))^w\\
&= \exp(w\cdot\log(\exp(z\cdot\log(e)))\\
&= \exp(w\cdot\log(\exp(z)))\\
&= \exp(w\cdot (z+2\pi \mathrm{i}k)) \qquad \forall k\in \mathbb{N}\\
&= \mathrm{e}^{w\cdot z+2\pi \mathrm{i}k\cdot w}
\end{align*}$$

I'm not sure if this is correct. Any hints?

Comment: Line 1 to 2 seems to be a problem.  How did $w$ get inside the argument of the exponential?  If that works, why do you need the $\log$ at all?

Comment: Let $\exp(z\cdot \log(e))=u$ Then one get: $u^w = \exp(w\cdot \log(u))=\exp(w\cdot\log(\exp(z\cdot\log(e)))$. For me, that seems the easiest way to prove.

Comment: There is no canonical way to define $u^w$ for $u$ and $w$ complex valued, hence one can wonder whether the statement you are proposing to prove, is founded at all.

Comment: This kind of thing depends specifically on the definitions you are using. Is $e^z$ a multi-valued function, or is it the same as $\exp(z)$ defined as a power series?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews We defined it this way: $exp: \{ z\in\mathbb{C}: a\leq \Im (z) < a+2\pi\}$

Comment: That's not a definition. What is $a$, what is $\exp(z)$? What is $e^z$?

Comment: Sorry. We defined $\exp(z)$ as a power series, so $\exp(z)=e^z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most of the comments indicate this is more about fiddling with the definitions and trying not to get it wrong, since a complex number to a complex power is not very well defined.  I'd suggest 
\begin{align}
(e^z)^w & = e^{w\log {e^z}} && \text{Using the definition } s^t= e^{t\log s}\text{ for }s, t \in \Bbb{C} \\
& =e^{w(z+2n\pi i)} && \log {e^z} = z+2n\pi i \\
& = e^{wz+2n\pi i w}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For complex $a, b$, we define $a^b$  as the multivalued function $\exp(b \log(a))$, where $\log(a)$ is any of the branches of the logarithm of $a$.
However, $e^b$ is conventionally taken to be $\exp(b)$, which is not multivalued.
Under this interpretation,

$$(e^z)^w = \exp(w \log(e^z)) = \exp(w (z+2 \pi i k)) = \exp(w z + 2 \pi i k w)$$

where $k$ is any integer (that's $\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb N$).